# Thunderbird - add CC when writing to specific contact

Tags: email, thunderbird

We have few customers where we are in contact with person responsible for communication with us at customer's side. It is required to send CC to this person's boss when we write an email to them. Is there any way to do it automatically? It would be great if I could add "compulsory CC" to any Contact and when this person is specified as a recipient, CC would be automatically updates. I've been trying to find an add-on for this but I don't think there is one.

**EDIT**: Tools > Account Settings, Copies & Folders is not a solution. I understand that it works in such a way that when I write *any* email, designated person (or persons) get copy. What I want is:

When I write an email to person@client1.com, then boss@client1.com is automatically added to CC. Then I write email to person@otherclient.com, and boss@otherclient.com and cto@otherclient.com are added to CC and so on.  As you can see we'd have to setup separate email account for each client (client1-contact@ourcompany.com, otherclient-contact@ourcompany.com) if we wanted to implement it using settings from *Tool > Account Setting, Copies & Folders*. This would be most probably error prone and would quickly get unwieldy.

Comment: Try the following "Select Tools > Account Settings in Thunderbird and then Copies & Folders for the mail account you want to configure automatic recipients for.  Here you can enable CC or BCC these email addresses so that every message gets automatically CCed or BCCed."

Comment: Thank you, but that's not it. What I want is not to CC every mail that I write but to have automatic, proper CC when I mail specific person. I'll edit my post so that it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

So...i think the best thing to do would be to create a template/draft.
Start the template by filling the recipient (person@client1.com) and the cc field with all the addresses you wish to link (boss@client1.com). Save the template.

Now every time you want to write an email to person@client1.com, just open up that template and boss@client1.com will already be there.

Maybe best to just Save a temporary subject so that you know which template your choosing